# How to access/include evaluated PHP script in HTML?

Tags: php, ajax, web-services

I'm using nusoap to create a webservice that sends commands from a remote control (client) to the server where these commands are evaluated. Now, I need to access the data calculated from the function of the webservice by another client.
Currently, I'm trying to do this via AJAX. I think I need to decouple the webservice from the script that handles the AJAX but how do I access the data from the webservice? I tried it with session variables but it is not working. Here is my code example:

**AJAX**

```
if(isset($_POST['source'])){
if(isset($_SESSION['commandResult'])){
    unset($_SESSION['commandResult']);
}
    while(!isset($_SESSION['commandResult'])){
        session_write_close();
        usleep(2000000); //wait 2 seconds
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['commandResult'] && $_SESSION['commandResult']!= "ready")){
            echo $_SESSION['commandResult'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**WS function**

```
function executeCommand($command) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['commandResult'] = "ready";
if($command=="resume"){
    $_SESSION['commandResult'] = "resume";
}

else if($command=="pause"){
    $_SESSION['commandResult'] = "pause";
}
else {
    $_SESSION['commandResult'] = $command;
}
return $_SESSION['commandResult'];
session_write_close();
}
```

I also tried putting the webservice directly into the index.php but nusoap doesn't like that (extra content at the end of file errors).
Is there another totally different best practice here?

Comment: Can you show the code for your ajax request?

Comment: "Now, I need to access the data calculated from the function of the webservice by **another client**." Please explain what you mean by another client, this is important

Comment: The AJAX works fine. By another client, I mean that the remote control is an HTML file run e.g. on a smartphone that sends commands to the server via AJAX where the webservice function is called. On a desktop (2nd client), a slideshow is run that uses long polling (via AJAX) to check whether there are any commands sent through the webservice. Hope that is clear enough :)

Comment: Yes, thats much clearer. It also explains why your code is failing - session data is unique to each client, one cannot access the others data. What you need is some kind of shared persistent storage, ie a database (sql, nosql or simple key value store). Or if this is just a proof of concept, you could even write to a simple text file on the server

Comment: But I thought I declouped the two clients by using a webservice, i.e. the webservice script and the long polling script run on the same server.